# jquery fade-in and out loop after json not working unless I use debugger

Tags: jquery, fadein, getjson, fadeout

**css** (just for some styling):

```
body {font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;background: #dedede;}

.weather {width: 350px;margin: 0px auto;text-align: center;text-transform: uppercase;}
.wx h2 {margin: 0 0 8px;color: #fff;background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);font-size: 48px;font-weight: 300;text-align: center;text-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);}
.wx ul {margin: 0;padding: 0;}
.wx li {background: #fff;background: rgba(255,255,255,0.90);padding: 5px;display: inline-block;border-radius: 5px;margin:0 5px;}
.wx {margin: 0 5px;}
#weather2 {margin-top: 0px;}

.wx {width:460px;}
```

**javascript** (header):

```
function InOut( elem )
{
 elem.delay()
     .fadeIn(2000)
     .delay(4000)
     .fadeOut( function(){ 
                   if(elem.next().length > 0)
                   {InOut( elem.next() );}
                   else
                   {InOut( elem.siblings(':first'));}
                 });
}
```

**html**:

```
<div id="wx" class="weather"></div>


<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

var weatherstations = 
   [{"Name":"las vegas, nv","Code":"KLAS"},
    {"Name":"north las vegas, nv","Code":"KVGT"}];

  $.each(weatherstations , function(key,value) {
     $.getJSON('http://www.domain.com/getwx-json.php?station=' + value.Code, function(result){
        $('#wx').append('<div class="wx"><h2>'+result.temp+'</h2><ul><li>'+value.Name+'</li><li>'+result.clouds+'</li><li>'+result.wind+'</li></ul></div>');
     }); //.getjson
  }); //.each weatherstations
});


$(function(){
$('.wx').hide();
InOut( $('.wx:first') );
});

</script>
```

When I run this, EVERYTHING shows up... the list of items just is listed one after the other.
If I go into the console and put a block at $('.wx').hide(); and refresh the page, nothing shows up and the script stops at that line. When I continue the script... THEN everything works the way it's supposed to: showing 1 item, fading in and out and showing the other, etc. etc.
Why does it do this? What am I missing?

Comment: your getJSON's ajax requests are finishing after the .wx hide stuff fires, generally, firing a bunch of ajax requests in a loop like that is a bad idea.  You should try to consolidate them all into one request if possible, then do the wx hide stuff at the end of that ajax requests done or success callback.

Comment: Why are you calling `delay()` twice in your InOut function?

Comment: `$('#wx')` is this a typo? Should it be `$('.wx')`? static id selector doesn't seem to belong in `each()`.

Comment: @EternalHour there is one #wx and in there are several divs with class wx. I know that it's a little confusing..

Comment: @Rooster I can add the hide to the json calls and then add the success which would have the function call to inout, is that correct? How can I put the son calls into 1 request?

Comment: I'm confused about what you are trying to do, each `$('.wx')` should fade in and out in sequence?

Comment: @EternalHour That is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrote the body to:

```
<div id="wx" class="weather"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var weatherstations = 
   [{"Name":"las vegas, nv","Code":"KLAS"},
    {"Name":"north las vegas, nv","Code":"KVGT"}];


function Readdata(ms) {
  var gets = [];
  $.each(ms, function(key,value) {
     $.ajax({ 
         type: 'GET', 
         url: 'http://www.domain.com/getwx-json.php?station=' + value.Code, 
         data: { get_param: 'value' }, 
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function(result){
        $('#wx').append('<div class="wx"><h2>'+result.temp+'</h2><ul><li>'+value.Name+'</li><li>'+result.clouds+'</li><li>'+result.wind+'</li></ul></div>');
         }
     }); //ajax call
  }); //each
}; // Readdata


$( document ).ready(Readdata(weatherstations));
$( document ).ajaxStop(function() {
      $('.wx').hide();
      InOut( $('.wx:first') );
});

</script>
```

And now it works like a charm.